# Bitnami unknown error when starting mysql and apache

Tags: mysql, apache, service, bitnami

When attempting to start the mysql and apache services from the Bitnami Wamp stack manager i get the following error.

> Starting MySQL Database... Exit code: 1 Stdout:
>
> Stderr: Unknown error starting mysql

I have been able to start the mysql server manually by navigating to the mysql/bin folder and running mysqld, but this is a less than desirable solution.

I tried running the **net start "wampstackMySQL"** command in cmd, which i found in the *mysql/scripts/servicesrun.bat* file, but i get the following error.

```
System error 1058 has occurred.

The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
```

In the services monitor (windows tool) i find both apache and mysql, but all the options for them are greyed out.

[image: services monitor]

There seems to be an issue with the mysql and apache services, but i am unable to figure out what and how to solve this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. You can try to reinstall the services by running the serviceinstall.bat file inside your installation directory. You will need to open a command prompt and run `serviceinstall.bat REMOVE` and `serviceinstall.bat INSTALL`. You can find more information [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/faq/windows-faq/administration/backup-restore-windows/#restore). If you can't start the services later, please take a look at the Apache and MySQL log files (installdir/apache2/logs/error_log and installdir/mysql/data/mysqld.log)

Comment: Hi. I tried the .bat files, but it didn't work and since it there is an exit at the end of those i tried to run the commands in the .bat file directly in cmd.  The service is removed successfully and is installed again. I get the following feedback when running start command: 
The wampstackMySQL service is starting.
The wampstackMySQL service could not be started.

The service did not report an error.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.
NET HELPMSG 3534 tells me "the service did not report an error".

Comment: Did you take a look at the installdir/mysql/data/mysqld.log file? You should see the error messages there.

Comment: The latest error i get in the log:
2021-05-08T08:58:26.484916Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2021-05-08T08:58:26.485381Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2021-05-08T08:58:26.706488Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2021-05-08T08:58:26.707680Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-05-08T08:58:26.708121Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2021-05-08T08:58:26.708477Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting